# Better way for pagination

Tags: codeigniter

If I want to do the pagination, I have to fetch data twice, one for get total rows, one for get the rows with limit, for example

```
<?php

class Admins extends CI_Model
{
    public function dataTotal()
    {
        $total = $this->db->get('admins')->num_rows();

        return  $total;
    }

    public function data()
    {
        return $this->db->limit(10, $this->start)->get('admins')->result();
    }
}
```

Then assign total to pagination and assign the data to view, it's quite make sense, but if there are a lot of conditions, I need to do it twice, for example:

```
<?php

class Admins extends CI_Model
{
    public function dataTotal()
    {
        $db = $this->db->from('admins')
                ->where('id >', 1)
                ->like('name', 'abc', 'both');

        return $db->get()->num_rows();
    }

    public function data()
    {
        $data = $this->db->from('admins')
                ->where('id >', 1)
                ->like('name', 'abc', 'both')
                ->limit(10, $this->start);

        return $data->get()->result();
    }
}
```

More conditions means more duplicated code, any way to make condition filter as one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function and use an SQL query as a parameter, that would be the most recommended option. If that's not an option you could do something like this:

```
public function data($option = "default")
{
    if($option == 'default')
    {
        $data = $this->db->from('admins')
            ->where('id >', 1)
            ->like('name', 'abc', 'both')
    }
    else if($option == 'other')
    {
        $data = $this->db->from('admins')
            ->where('id >', 1)
            ->like('name', 'abc', 'both')
            ->limit(10, $this->start);
    }

    return $data->get()->result();
}
```

And then calling it:

```
data();
data("other");
```

That's the most efficient way I can come up with.